# Как запретить диспетчеру задач закрывать определенный процесс?

Tags: процесс, vb.net, visual-basic, диспетчер-задач

Хочу сделать так, чтобы когда я в диспетчере задач нажимал завершить процесс в диалоговом окне, там где спрашивается действительно ли хочу завершить, кнопка завершить ставала неактивной. Буду рад любым методам, но особенно интересует решение на VB .NET

Comment: Вопрос касается только стандартного диспетчера задач?

Comment: @gil9red да, но желательно и с подобными нму программами, допустим process hacker